# Node child_process.spawn multiple commands

Tags: node.js, keytool, spawn

I wan to automate the creation and extracting of keystore.
The problem I'm facing is how to join the commands using the ' **|** ' symbol or similar solution.

```
//Original Command    
var command='keytool -exportcert -storepass mypass -keypass mypass  
-alias myalias -keystore mykey.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64';

//Arguments for the spawn    
var keyArgs = [
      '-exportcert',
      '-storepass','mypass',
      '-keypass','mypass',
      '-alias','myalias',
      '-keystore',"myjey.keystore",


      'openssl','sha1',
      '-binary',
      'openssl','base64',


  ];
exec('keytool',keyArgs,{cwd:appCreateFolder+"/"+opt.id+"/Certificates"},function(e){
    console.log(chalk.cyan('Key created'));
      })
```

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Comment: I'm having the same problem! did you find a solution for this? the provided one did not helped me out

Answer (score 66):

From Node.js v6 you can specify a `shell` option in `spawn` method which will run command using shell and thus it is possible to **chain commands using spawn method**.

For example this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('ls && ls && ls', {
  shell: true
});
child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.error("STDERR:", data.toString());
});
child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log("STDOUT:", data.toString());
});
child.on('exit', function (exitCode) {
  console.log("Child exited with code: " + exitCode);
});
```

Will trigger an error on node.js version less than 6:

```
Error: spawn ls && ls && ls ENOENT
```

But on version 6 and higher it will return expected result:

```
node app.js
STDOUT: app.js

STDOUT: app.js
app.js

Child exited with code: 0
```

Answer (score 20):

The `|` symbol on the command line is called "piping" because it's like piping streams of data together. What you want is to get ahold of the `stdin` (Standard In) and `stdout` (Standard Out) streams for the commands you're executing.

For example, this is how you would spawn the echo command and pipe it's output to grep:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var echo = spawn('echo', ['The quick brown fox\njumped over the lazy dog.']);
var grep = spawn('grep', ['brown']);

echo.stdout.pipe(grep.stdin);
grep.stdout.pipe(process.stdin);
```

The above example spawns both the "echo" and "grep" commands. It pipes any output from the `echo` process's `stdout` stream to the `grep` process's `stdin` stream. Finally we pipe the `grep` process's `stdout` stream to the parent process's (your node process) `stdin` stream so you can see the output in your terminal.

The output would be "The quick brown fox" because I put a newline character in the middle and the grep only matched the first line containing "brown".

You could use the `exec` function to achieve the same result. Just might be harder to maintain in the future, but if all you need is to quickly run a set of piped commands, you can enter the full command line string (including pipe symbols) and pass it to `exec`.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmdString = 'grep "The quick brown fox\njumped over the lazy dog." | grep "brown"';
exec(cmdString, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Or instead of passing in the callback function you could just pipe the output to `process.stdin` if all you care about is seeing the command output.

```
exec(cmdString).stdout.pipe(process.stdin);
```

---

Here's a quick example of what I believe your code should look like using `spawn`. May require tweaks since it seems specific to what you're doing.

```
var keyArgs = [
  '-exportcert',
  '-storepass','mypass',
  '-keypass','mypass',
  '-alias','myalias',
  '-keystore',"myjey.keystore",
  'openssl','sha1',
  '-binary',
  'openssl','base64',
];
var keyOpts = {
  cwd: `${appCreateFolder}/${opt.id}/Certificates`
};

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var keytool = spawn('keytool', keyArgs, keyOpts);
var opensslBinary = spawn('openssl', ['sha1', '-binary']);
var opensslBase64 = spawn('openssl', ['base64']);

keytool.stdout.pipe(opensslBinary.stdin);
opensslBinary.stdout.pipe(opensslBase64.stdin);
opensslBase64.stdout.pipe(process.stdin);

opensslBase64.on('close', () => {
  console.log(chalk.cyan('Key created.'));
});
```

Or using `exec`:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmdString = 'keytool -exportcert -storepass mypass -keypass mypass -alias myalias -keystore mykey.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64';
var cmdOpts = {
  cwd: `${appCreateFolder}/${opt.id}/Certificates`
};
exec(cmdString, cmdOpts, () => {
  console.log(chalk.cyan('Key created.'));
});
```

Comment: I believe in the last spawn example, the last 5 elements of the keyArgs array (from 'openssl') should be removed since they are now captured in the subsequent spawns.